# Swift Array/Dictionary is not printing back in expected order

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

Im attempting to to combine two swift arrays into a simple swift dictionary. I am extremely new to swift (but know a decent amount of python), and have come across something that I think is rather odd. When I run the code below, I get a dictionary just as expected, however, if I rerun the code, the key:value pairs come up in a different order. I know that dictionaries in swift are supposed to be unordered, but does this mean each time I go to iterate through the key:value pairs of a dictionary, the order of these pairings may change? In other words, is it impossible to preserve the order to the two initial arrays that comprise the dictionary in the final dictionary product?

```
let cities: Array<String> = ["Paris", "Mexico City", "Rome"]
let countries: Array<String> = ["France", "Mexico", "Italy"]

var newCountrydict : Dictionary<String, String> = [:]
for (city,country) in zip(cities,countries){
    newCountrydict[country] = city

}

newCountrydict
```

Comment: Dictionaries always in unordered. maybe you can say they lay on heap or stack, not in order. If you want to keep order the same all the time then use Array.

Comment: You are correct, a dictionary is entirely unordered and always will be. If you have a particular reqt to keep the order then I'd suggest asking a question on how to do this, or reword this question. Depending on the use case, you could either (a) use an array of pairs, or (b) live with the dictionary being unordered. All depends on what you want to do with the data.

Comment: *”I know that dictionaries in swift are supposed to be unordered”*. Dictionaries are unordered by definition in most languages.

Comment: When you **lookup** values by keys, the order of the key-value pair is useless. You can't devise anything if the orders are preserved in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [swift docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html), under "Dictionaries":

> Unlike items in an array, items in a dictionary do not have a specified order. You use a dictionary when you need to look up values based on their identifier, in much the same way that a real-world dictionary is used to look up the definition for a particular word.

It is not possible to preserve the order if you use dictionaries in swift.

In the same docs, it says:

> Arrays are ordered collections of values. Sets are unordered collections of unique values. Dictionaries are unordered collections of key-value associations.

I suggest you read through the [official documents](https://docs.swift.org/).